# How can I get the mount path of a USB device on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, usb, mount

I have a backup script that backs up some data to a USB device.  The problem I have is that OSX sometimes changes the expected mount path.  For example if some file is locked under the expected mount path, OSX mounts it on another path.  A USB device named 'BACKUP' can be mounted at /Volumes/BACKUP-1 instead of /Volumes/BACKUP.

Is there a way to finding out the current mount path of a USB device in the OSX Terminal?  Something like 'mount_path BACKUP' (command is fake) which would then return '/Volumes/BACKUP-1' or nothing if the device was not mounted?

Answer (score 89):

The following commands show you information about mounted volumes:

- The well-known Unix `mount`, showing e.g. `/dev/disk5s3` mounted at `/Volumes/Foo`
- `diskutil list` shows an overview of all disks and volumes
- `diskutil info /dev/disk5s3` shows information about that volume, including a `Volume UUID` that can be used to uniquely identify that volume.

You can query `diskutil info` by using the volume's UUID:

```
$ diskutil info DEC8759E-F77D-3EAE-B3EB-B6438F1AA428 | grep 'Mount Point'
   Mount Point:              /Volumes/DroboOne
```

---

Sample command output on my system:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
localhost:/bNqIvVr1ZdFBdf19Io81Q4 on /Volumes/MobileBackups (mtmfs, nosuid, read-only, nobrowse)
/dev/disk4 on /Volumes/MyBook (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled)
/dev/disk5s3 on /Volumes/DroboOne (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
/dev/disk7s3 on /Volumes/DroboTwo (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
/dev/disk6s3 on /Volumes/DroboThree (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
```

---

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *256.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         240.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Servus10 HD            *239.7 GB   disk1
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         3.0 TB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS MyBook                 *3.0 TB     disk4
/dev/disk5
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *2.2 TB     disk5
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk5s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS DroboOne                2.2 TB     disk5s3
/dev/disk6
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *2.2 TB     disk6
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk6s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS DroboThree              2.2 TB     disk6s3
/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *2.2 TB     disk7
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk7s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS DroboTwo                2.2 TB     disk7s3
```

---

```
$ diskutil info /dev/disk5s3
   Device Identifier:        disk5s3
   Device Node:              /dev/disk5s3
   Part of Whole:            disk5
   Device / Media Name:      Untitled

   Volume Name:              DroboOne
   Escaped with Unicode:     DroboOne

   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /Volumes/DroboOne
   Escaped with Unicode:     /Volumes/DroboOne

   File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                  Journal size 172032 KB at offset 0x4001000
   Owners:                   Disabled

   Partition Type:           Apple_HFS
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 FireWire
   SMART Status:             Not Supported
   Volume UUID:              DEC8759E-F77D-3EAE-B3EB-B6438F1AA428

   Total Size:               2.2 TB (2198888927232 Bytes) (exactly 4294704936 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Volume Free Space:        169.4 GB (169412173824 Bytes) (exactly 330883152 512-Byte-Blocks)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    No
   Internal:                 No
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having to use those commands and parsing my way through this :)  But if there is no other way, do you know of any bash functions that do this for you?

Comment: @xastor Added relevant info. `man diskutil` would have helped.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a script now and it works.  I was hoping there was another way though, I should have mentioned that in the question.  For example, what happens on an OSX system with another language?  I cannot grep 'Mount Volume' on a french system I suppose..

Comment: @xastor `diskutil` is not localized.

Comment: This is a dependable solution then.  Thank you!

Comment: @xastor Alternatively, just grep for `/Volumes/` and ignore the label. It's always there unless you roll your own solution.

Comment: This old reply just helped me! "diskutil info /dev/disk5s3" to convert the /dev/(foo) to a volume. Many thanks!

Answer (score 11):

What about this command:

```
df -lH | grep "Filesystem"; df -lH | grep "/Volumes/*"
```

In the column "Mounted on" you get all the Mount Points of all devices mounted on `"/Volumes"`, which in my case are almost always USB devices ;-)

The `grep` commands basically skip the hard drive which is mounted on `"/"`.

In the terminal of my OSX Snow Leopard, I use it for quick overview of the Mount Points of my currently connected USB Devices. If you are only interested in Mount Points and not all the other parameters as UUID etc., this would be in my opinion the more straight forward way rather than `"diskutil"` with all its information.

Comment: `grep "/Volumes/"` is the same as `grep "/Volumes/*"`.

Answer (score 2):

I retrieve it in a variable:

```
media=\`df | grep "media" | awk '{print $6}'\`
```

or

```
media=$(df | awk '/media/ {print $6}')
```

The `df` command lists the partitions, the resulting output is piped as input to the grep command which filters and keeps only the lines containing the word media, which is then piped to the `awk` command which only keeps the 6th column of its one line input.

Comment: The second form should be much preferred, but it's not obvious how to pass in the `/media/` regex parametrized.  Try `media=$(df | awk -v regex="$regex" '$1 ~ regex { print $6 }')` to pass in the shell variable `$regex` as the thing to search for.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this bash script :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Retrieves the mount point of an OSX volume name or UUID.
# @param $1 Name of the volume or UUID of the volume.
# @return returns the mount path or an empty string if the volume is not mounted. 
#
diskutil info $1 | grep 'Mount Point' | cut -d : -f 2 | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/ *$//g';
```

Comment: This was last September, and nobody's commented on it yet? your 'Mount Point' SHOULD instead be 'Device Node' if you expect this script to do what the comments say it does.

Comment: @Blakat The device node is not what the OP was asking for. The mount point is `/Volumes/…`, which is what everyone was talking about if I read this question correctly.

Comment: If you are using `sed` anyway, the `grep` and the `cut` are [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); `diskutil info "$1" | sed -n '/^ *Mount Point: */!d;s///;s/ *$//p'`

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me because it considered white spaces +1

Answer (score 1):

Just the good old `diskutil`. This isn't Linux, where you can probably peek into /sys or something.

```bsh
diskutil info "$VolumeName" | grep "Mount Point" | tr " " "\n" | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use fstab for this.
There's a thread regarding this topic here on Super User: [Mac Lion: fstab is deprecated. so what replaces it to prevent a partition from mounting?](https://superuser.com/questions/336455/mac-lion-fstab-is-deprecated-so-what-replaces-it-to-prevent-a-partition-from-m)

Comment: And *how* would you use `fstab` for this, exactly?

Comment: Taking the UUId of the USB drive, creating a mount point and giving all of it to /etc/fstab. Whenever the aforementioned USB drive is attached, will be mounted on that mount point, recognized by its UUID.

Comment: Note that the user's problem comes from the default mount point already being in use due.

Comment: That's what I meant: giving the OS a mount point by using /etc/fstab. From that time on, the system will read /etc/fstab, find that there's a UUID with an associated mount point, and it will use that instead of the default one.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my shell scripts on OS X

```
df | awk '{print $6}' | grep -Ex "/Volumes/myvolume"
```

Comment: Can you add a few sentences to explain how this works?  Thanks.

Comment: This is a roundabout way of saying `df | awk '$6 == "/Volumes/myvolume" { print $6 }'` i.e. print the volume path if it is exactly the expected one.  The `grep -E` flag is superfluous here and the [`grep` is useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) because Awk already knows quite well how to match a regular expression.

Comment: A more useful command would probably grep for the volume *before* printing only the sixth field, or even better change the first `$6` to `$1` in my previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

This might work better:

```
df -lH | grep -E "*putinyourvolumelabel*$" | awk '{print $1}''
```

Comment: *Why* might that work better?

Comment: Dennis, welcome to Super User.  A couple of the other answers aren't good examples, but the goal of answers is to educate rather than just provide cut and paste code.  I'm not a coder, so I can't address how good your solution might be, but I suspect bertieb's comment, and perhaps the downvote, go to the fact that this is just unexplained code, rather than to the quality of solution.  Can you add a few sentences to explain what this does, and what makes it a better solution than whatever you were comparing it to?  Thanks.

Comment: This code only reads me a strange poem