# How to move the Users folder to a new drive in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks

How can I move the 'Users' folder from my main drive onto a new drive (which I just installed on my MacBook Pro by replacing the optical drive with a 2nd HD)?

The goal is to separate the application and system (main SSD) and the data (separate HD).

Edit: I have never used Unix and I would prefer a solution that uses OS X graphical UI.

Answer (score 1):

1. First, mount your new disk to a standard mountpoint, like */mnt*. Make sure that you have the required permissions to read, write, and execute files as yourself, not as sudo.
2. Now copy onto it the contents of /Users, preserving the files' attributes (the *-p* option).

   cp -Rp /Users /mnt
3. Modify your /etc/fstab file to instruct it to mount the partition you just mounted at /mnt at the mountpoint /Users instead. Please notice that, contrary to some ridiculous rumors floating around, /etc/fstab is **not** deprecated in recent OS X versions, see for instance an excellent discussion [in this very forum](https://superuser.com/questions/336455/mac-lion-fstab-is-deprecated-so-what-replaces-it-to-prevent-a-partition-from-m). Also, you most likely do not have an /etc/fstab file because in Mac there is no need for it, so you will have to create one.
4. Rename the old /Users folder to something easy to remember:

   mv /Users /Old-Users
5. Reboot and check that everything is alright. If it is, erase the directory /Old-Users.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure I understand all those commands - are those Unix commands? I'll have to research that.

Comment: @JDelage Yes, they are all Unix commands.